# Getting "Type Mismatch" with VBA PivotTables and Filter Dates

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table, cube

I'm writing a script in Excel VBA (MS0 365 - version 1708).

The objective of the script is to apply different date ranges to "pre-structured" pivot tables, the pivot tables are connected to a Tabular Cube.

I have Googled and have seen similar issues but I haven't found any solutions to my issue unfortunately

In the script, I loop through the years and then the Quarters, Months and finally the Dates as needed (the dates are calculated via a worksheet), the idea here is to simulate what a user does with his mouse, but I understand that there might be a more efficient method? (I have tried `.PivotFilters.Add2` instead but it doesn't seem to work seen as it is a `xlPageField` field).

So at the moment with the below Sub, for a given PivotTable, in order to select for example all dates starting from the 1st of January 2017 up until Sunday the 8th of April included I will select :

1. 2017
2. then the first Quarter of 2018 (called "T1-JFM" below)
3. then nothing for Months
4. then all the dates of April up until the 8th included

However, once I hit the Sub that concerns the Dates, I get an error on the line:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields(DIM_DATE_PTF).VisibleItemsList = Array(DIM_ARRAY)
```

There I get a:

> "Run-time error '13' : Type mismatch

that line is the line that actually *applies* the Date filters, (prior to applying the filters `DIM_ARRAY` is an Array that "accumulates" the strings used in the filter).

I have tried adding another quotation mark to `DIM_ARRAY` at the beginning and the end of the array to ensure that it wasn't badly evaluated as a string, this didn't work out.

The **Dates Sub portion** is this :

```
Private Sub Cycle_Date(YEAR_i_max As String, TRIMESTRE_i As String,MONTH_i As String, MONTH_i_max As Integer)

i = 0
DATE_i_min = StdFilter(SheetName, "DATE_i_min")
DATE_i_max = StdFilter(SheetName, "DATE_i_max")

For i = DATE_i_min To DATE_i_max
DATE_i=WorksheetFunction.Proper(WorksheetFunction.Text(DateSerial(YEAR_i_max
,MONTH_i_max, i), "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS"))


DIM_ARRAY_elmt = DIM_DATE_SUB & DIM_DATE_MOD_YEAR & ".&[" & YEAR_i_max & "]" 
& ".&[" & TRIMESTRE_i & "]" & ".&[" & MONTH_i & "]" & ".&[" & DATE_i & "]"
'Debug.Print DIM_ARRAY_elmt

If i = DATE_i_min Then
DIM_ARRAY = DIM_ARRAY_elmt

ElseIf i = DATE_i_max Then
    DIM_ARRAY = DIM_ARRAY & """" & "," & """" & DIM_ARRAY_elmt

ElseIf DIM_ARRAY <> "" Then
    DIM_ARRAY = DIM_ARRAY & """" & "," & """" & DIM_ARRAY_elmt

End If

Next

'Debug.Print DIM_ARRAY
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields(DIM_DATE_PTF).VisibleItemsList = Array(DIM_ARRAY)
```

Below is the entire macro. The Dim(s) are at the top and Functions at the bottom. How can I resolve this?

```
Option Explicit

Dim DIM_DATE_CREATION_BASE As String
Dim DIM_DATE_SUB As String
Dim DIM_DATE_PTF As String

Dim DIM_DATE_MOD_YEAR As String
Dim DIM_DATE_MOD_TRIMESTRE As String
Dim DIM_DATE_MOD_MONTH As String
Dim DIM_DATE_MOD_DATE As String

Dim DIM_ARRAY As Variant
Dim DIM_ARRAY_elmt As String

Dim YEAR_i As Integer
Dim YEAR_i_min As String
Dim YEAR_i_max As String

Dim TRIMESTRE_i As String
Dim TRIMESTRE_i_max As String
Dim TRIMESTRE_i_min As String

Dim MONTH_i As String
Dim MONTH_i_max As Integer
Dim MONTH_i_min As Integer

Dim DATE_i As String
Dim DATE_i_min As Integer
Dim DATE_i_max As Integer

Dim i As Integer

Dim ws As Variant
Dim SheetNames As Variant
Dim SheetName As String

Dim Continue_Flag As Boolean


Sub Launch_Update()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Call Date_Filters

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub


Private Sub Date_Filters()

Continue_Flag = True

SheetNames = Array("NOW", "A-0 || J-7", "A-1 || à Date Equiv.", "A-1 || J-7 Atterissage")

DIM_DATE_CREATION_BASE = "[DIM_DATE_CREATION].[CALENDRIER_CREATION]"
DIM_DATE_SUB = DIM_DATE_CREATION_BASE & DIM_DATE_MOD_YEAR

For Each ws In SheetNames

Sheets(ws).Select
SheetName = ActiveSheet.Name


DIM_DATE_MOD_YEAR = ".[ANNEE]"
DIM_DATE_PTF = DIM_DATE_CREATION_BASE & DIM_DATE_MOD_YEAR

Call Cycle_Year

DIM_DATE_MOD_TRIMESTRE = ".[TRIMESTRE]"
DIM_DATE_PTF = DIM_DATE_CREATION_BASE & DIM_DATE_MOD_TRIMESTRE

Call Cycle_Trimestre(YEAR_i_max)

DIM_DATE_MOD_MONTH = ".[MOIS]"
DIM_DATE_PTF = DIM_DATE_CREATION_BASE & DIM_DATE_MOD_MONTH

Call Cycle_Month(YEAR_i_max, TRIMESTRE_i)

DIM_DATE_MOD_DATE = ".[DATE]"
DIM_DATE_PTF = DIM_DATE_CREATION_BASE & DIM_DATE_MOD_DATE

Call Cycle_Date(YEAR_i_max, TRIMESTRE_i, MONTH_i, MONTH_i_max)


Next ws

Continue_Flag = False

MsgBox "Date Filter Sub has ended"

End Sub

Private Sub Cycle_Year()

YEAR_i_min = StdFilter(SheetName, "YEAR_i_min")
YEAR_i_max = StdFilter(SheetName, "YEAR_i_max")

If YEAR_i_min = YEAR_i_max Then
YEAR_i_max = YEAR_i_min + 1
End If


For YEAR_i = YEAR_i_min To YEAR_i_max - 1

DIM_ARRAY_elmt = DIM_DATE_PTF & ".&[" & YEAR_i & "]"

If YEAR_i = YEAR_i_min Then
DIM_ARRAY = DIM_ARRAY_elmt

ElseIf YEAR_i = YEAR_i_max - 1 Then
DIM_ARRAY = DIM_ARRAY & "," & DIM_ARRAY_elmt

ElseIf DIM_ARRAY <> "" Then
DIM_ARRAY = DIM_ARRAY & "," & DIM_ARRAY_elmt

End If

Next



ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields(DIM_DATE_PTF).VisibleItemsList = Array(DIM_ARRAY)


End Sub

Private Sub Cycle_Trimestre(YEAR_i_max As String)


TRIMESTRE_i_min = StdFilter(SheetName, "TRIMESTRE_i_min")
TRIMESTRE_i_max = StdFilter(SheetName, "TRIMESTRE_i_max")

For i = TRIMESTRE_i_min To TRIMESTRE_i_max

If i = 1 Then
TRIMESTRE_i = "T1 - JFM"

ElseIf i = 2 Then
TRIMESTRE_i = "T2 - AMJ"

ElseIf i = 3 Then
TRIMESTRE_i = "T3 - JAS"

ElseIf i = 4 Then
TRIMESTRE_i = "T4 - OND"

End If


DIM_ARRAY_elmt = DIM_DATE_SUB & DIM_DATE_MOD_YEAR & ".&[" & YEAR_i_max & "]" & ".&[" & TRIMESTRE_i & "]"


If i = TRIMESTRE_i_min Then
DIM_ARRAY = DIM_ARRAY_elmt

ElseIf i = TRIMESTRE_i_max Then
DIM_ARRAY = DIM_ARRAY_elmt
GoTo ApplyFilter1

ElseIf DIM_ARRAY <> "" Then
DIM_ARRAY = DIM_ARRAY & "," & DIM_ARRAY_elmt

End If

Next

ApplyFilter1:

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields(DIM_DATE_PTF).VisibleItemsList = Array(DIM_ARRAY)


End Sub
Private Sub Cycle_Month(YEAR_i_max As String, TRIMESTRE_i As String)

i = 0
MONTH_i_min = StdFilter(SheetName, "MONTH_i_min")
MONTH_i_max = StdFilter(SheetName, "MONTH_i_max")


For i = MONTH_i_min To MONTH_i_max

MONTH_i = WorksheetFunction.Proper(WorksheetFunction.Text(DateSerial(2018, i, 1), "[$-40C]MMMM"))




DIM_ARRAY_elmt = DIM_DATE_SUB & DIM_DATE_MOD_YEAR & ".&[" & YEAR_i_max & "]" & ".&[" & TRIMESTRE_i & "]" & ".&[" & MONTH_i & "]"


If i = MONTH_i_min Then
DIM_ARRAY = DIM_ARRAY_elmt

ElseIf i = MONTH_i_max Then
DIM_ARRAY = DIM_ARRAY_elmt
GoTo ApplyFilter2

ElseIf DIM_ARRAY <> "" Then
DIM_ARRAY = DIM_ARRAY & "," & DIM_ARRAY_elmt

End If

Next

ApplyFilter2:

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields(DIM_DATE_PTF).VisibleItemsList = Array(DIM_ARRAY)

MONTH_i = WorksheetFunction.Proper(WorksheetFunction.Text(DateSerial(2018, i - 1, 1), "[$-40C]MMMM"))

End Sub
Private Sub Cycle_Date(YEAR_i_max As String, TRIMESTRE_i As String, MONTH_i As String, MONTH_i_max As Integer)

i = 0
DATE_i_min = StdFilter(SheetName, "DATE_i_min")
DATE_i_max = StdFilter(SheetName, "DATE_i_max")


For i = DATE_i_min To DATE_i_max

DATE_i = WorksheetFunction.Proper(WorksheetFunction.Text(DateSerial(YEAR_i_max, MONTH_i_max, i), "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS"))


DIM_ARRAY_elmt = DIM_DATE_SUB & DIM_DATE_MOD_YEAR & ".&[" & YEAR_i_max & "]" & ".&[" & TRIMESTRE_i & "]" & ".&[" & MONTH_i & "]" & ".&[" & DATE_i & "]"

Debug.Print DIM_ARRAY_elmt


If i = DATE_i_min Then
DIM_ARRAY = DIM_ARRAY_elmt

ElseIf i = DATE_i_max Then
DIM_ARRAY = DIM_ARRAY & """" & "," & """" & DIM_ARRAY_elmt

ElseIf DIM_ARRAY <> "" Then
DIM_ARRAY = DIM_ARRAY & """" & "," & """" & DIM_ARRAY_elmt

End If

Next

Debug.Print DIM_ARRAY

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields(DIM_DATE_PTF).VisibleItemsList = Array(DIM_ARRAY)

End Sub

Public Function StdFilter(SheetPointer As String, DateField As String)

StdFilter = WorksheetFunction.Index(Sheets("Standard_FILTERS").Range("A1:J5"), _
 WorksheetFunction.Match(SheetPointer, Sheets("Standard_FILTERS").Range("A:A"), 0), _
 WorksheetFunction.Match(DateField, Sheets("Standard_FILTERS").Range("1:1"), 0))

End Function
```

Comment: Can you try `ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields(DIM_DATE_PTF).VisibleItemsList = DIM_ARRAY`? Plus, when you `Debug.Print DIM_ARRAY` on the line above, what do you get?

Comment: In general, instead of `Array(DIM_ARRAY)` give it a try with the expected values in the array hard-coded. E.g. like this - `..._DATE_PTF)..VisibleItemsList = Array(CDate("08.04.2018"), CDate("09.05.2018"))`

Comment: `ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields(DIM_DATE_PTF).VisibleItemsList = DIM_ARRAY`
--> gives me a Run-time error 1004  Application defined or object defined error

Comment: Try the second option with the hardcoded values. Just make sure that they exist in the Pivot table. Then you simply have to create them in the array.

Comment: Debug.Print DIM_ARRAY
--> gives me [DIM_DATE_CREATION].[CALENDRIER_CREATION].[ANNEE].&[2018].&[T2 - AMJ].&[Avril].&[2018-04-01T00:00:00]","[DIM_DATE_CREATION].[CALENDRIER_CREATION].[ANNEE].&[2018].&[T2 - AMJ].&[Avril].&[2018-04-02T00:00:00]","[DIM_DATE_CREATION].[CALENDRIER_CREATION].[ANNEE].&[2018].&[T2 - AMJ].&[Avril].&[2018-04-03T00:00:00]","[DIM_DATE_CREATION].[CALENDRIER_CREATION].[ANNEE].&[2018].&[T2 - AMJ].&[Avril].&[2018-04-04T00:00:00]","[DIM_DATE_CREATION].[CALENDRIER_CREATION].[ANNEE].&[2018].&[T2 - AMJ].&[Avril].&[2018-04-05T00:00:00]","[DIM_DATE_CREATION].[CALENDRIER_CREATI...etc

Comment: Then the `DIM_ARRAY` is not an array but a string?

Comment: Hmm.. when I replaced DIM_ARRAY with the "Debug.Print" in Hardcoded + qutation marks on either extremities it worked !!!
but adding the line `DIM_ARRAY = """" & DIM_ARRAY & """"` before the `ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields(DIM_DATE_PTF).VisibleItemsList = DIM_ARRAY` does not solve the issue ... :S

Comment: Why do you need `DIM_ARRAY = """" & DIM_ARRAY & """"`?

Comment: Because if I hardcode DIM_ARRAY it will only work in the form "date1","date2","date3", etc.
otherwise DIM_ARRAY = date1","date2","date3
(quotation marks missing at the beginning and at the end)

Comment: Congrats, @Chunk222

Comment: Pro tips for posting: cut out the chat and waffle, and stick to facts and details. Don't excessively flatter your audience ("masters") as readers may just view this as obsequious. There's no need to say you'll respond to comments (it is expected) or beg and plead (it may irritate and result in downvotes). Just state the problem, cut it down to an [mcve] as much as you can, and (obviously) keep working on it after you have posted it. Self-answers are encouraged, but put these as answers below, rather than merging them with the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RESOLUTION**:

DIM_ARRAY had to be an *Array* data type and was a *String* data type (that resembled an array in a misleading manner but wasn't one).

I believe that the other portions of the code worked only because only 1 element was applied every time in the "fake array", what is certain is that the data/parameters used in the "test conditions" led me to a misleading diagnosis.

(Lesson learnt: change your test conditions to see if they allow you to gather new information)

Below the full code, that *really* works this time :

```
Private Sub Date_Filters()

        SheetNames = Array("NOW", "A-0 || J-7", "A-1 || à Date Equiv.", "A-1 || J-7 Atterissage") 'list of relevant sheets

        'setting variables:
        DIM_DATE_CREATION_BASE = "[DIM_DATE_CREATION].[CALENDRIER_CREATION]"
        DIM_DATE_SUB = DIM_DATE_CREATION_BASE & DIM_DATE_MOD_YEAR
        mymsg = "Dates à jour pour TDC :"
        i = 0

    For Each ws In SheetNames

        Sheets(ws).Select
        SheetName = ActiveSheet.Name

            DIM_DATE_MOD_YEAR = ".[ANNEE]"
            DIM_DATE_PTF = DIM_DATE_CREATION_BASE & DIM_DATE_MOD_YEAR

        Call Cycle_Year

            i = 0
            DIM_DATE_MOD_TRIMESTRE = ".[TRIMESTRE]"
            DIM_DATE_PTF = DIM_DATE_CREATION_BASE & DIM_DATE_MOD_TRIMESTRE

        Call Cycle_Trimestre(YEAR_i_max)

            i = 0
            DIM_DATE_MOD_MONTH = ".[MOIS]"
            DIM_DATE_PTF = DIM_DATE_CREATION_BASE & DIM_DATE_MOD_MONTH

        Call Cycle_Month(YEAR_i_max, TRIMESTRE_i)

            i = 0
            DIM_DATE_MOD_DATE = ".[DATE]"
            DIM_DATE_PTF = DIM_DATE_CREATION_BASE & DIM_DATE_MOD_DATE

        Call Cycle_Date(YEAR_i_max, TRIMESTRE_i, MONTH_i, MONTH_i_max)


        mymsg = mymsg & SheetName & " -ET- "
        Application.StatusBar = mymsg

    Next ws

End Sub

Private Sub Cycle_Year()

        YEAR_i_min = StdFilter(SheetName, "YEAR_i_min")
        YEAR_i_max = StdFilter(SheetName, "YEAR_i_max")
        ReDim TRUE_ARRAY(1 To 2)
        Erase TRUE_ARRAY
        ReDim TRUE_ARRAY(YEAR_i_min To YEAR_i_max)

    If YEAR_i_min = YEAR_i_max Then ' Fork-out scenario

        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields(DIM_DATE_PTF).VisibleItemsList = Array("")

        Exit Sub

    End If


    For YEAR_i = YEAR_i_min To YEAR_i_max - 1 ' Loop through

        DIM_ARRAY_elmt = DIM_DATE_PTF & ".&[" & YEAR_i & "]"
        TRUE_ARRAY(YEAR_i) = DIM_ARRAY_elmt

        Debug.Print "Year   "; YEAR_i; TRUE_ARRAY(YEAR_i)

    Next

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields(DIM_DATE_PTF).VisibleItemsList = TRUE_ARRAY

End Sub

Private Sub Cycle_Trimestre(YEAR_i_max As String)

        TRIMESTRE_i_min = StdFilter(SheetName, "TRIMESTRE_i_min")
        TRIMESTRE_i_max = StdFilter(SheetName, "TRIMESTRE_i_max")
        ReDim TRUE_ARRAY(1 To 2)
        Erase TRUE_ARRAY
        ReDim TRUE_ARRAY(TRIMESTRE_i_min To TRIMESTRE_i_max)

    If TRIMESTRE_i_min = TRIMESTRE_i_max Then ' Fork-out scenario

        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields(DIM_DATE_PTF).VisibleItemsList = Array("")

        Exit Sub

    End If


    For i = TRIMESTRE_i_min To TRIMESTRE_i_max ' Loop through

        If i = TRIMESTRE_i_max Then

                If i = 1 Then
                    TRIMESTRE_i = "T1 - JFM"

                    ElseIf i = 2 Then
                        TRIMESTRE_i = "T2 - AMJ"

                    ElseIf i = 3 Then
                        TRIMESTRE_i = "T3 - JAS"

                    ElseIf i = 4 Then
                        TRIMESTRE_i = "T4 - OND"

                End If

            GoTo ApplyFilter
            Else

                If i = 1 Then
                    TRIMESTRE_i = "T1 - JFM"

                    ElseIf i = 2 Then
                        TRIMESTRE_i = "T2 - AMJ"

                    ElseIf i = 3 Then
                        TRIMESTRE_i = "T3 - JAS"

                    ElseIf i = 4 Then
                        TRIMESTRE_i = "T4 - OND"

                End If
        End If

    DIM_ARRAY_elmt = DIM_DATE_SUB & DIM_DATE_MOD_YEAR & ".&[" & YEAR_i_max & "]" & ".&[" & TRIMESTRE_i & "]"
    TRUE_ARRAY(i) = DIM_ARRAY_elmt

    Debug.Print "Trimestre "; i; TRUE_ARRAY(i)

    Next

ApplyFilter:

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields(DIM_DATE_PTF).VisibleItemsList = TRUE_ARRAY

End Sub
Private Sub Cycle_Month(YEAR_i_max As String, TRIMESTRE_i As String)


        MONTH_i_min = StdFilter(SheetName, "MONTH_i_min")
        MONTH_i_max = StdFilter(SheetName, "MONTH_i_max")
        ReDim TRUE_ARRAY(1 To 2)
        Erase TRUE_ARRAY
        ReDim TRUE_ARRAY(MONTH_i_min To MONTH_i_max)

    If MONTH_i_min = MONTH_i_max Then ' Fork-out scenario

        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields(DIM_DATE_PTF).VisibleItemsList = Array("")

        MONTH_i = WorksheetFunction.Proper(WorksheetFunction.Text(DateSerial(2018, MONTH_i_min, 1), "[$-40C]MMMM"))

        Exit Sub

    End If

    For i = MONTH_i_min To MONTH_i_max - 1 ' Loop through

    MONTH_i = WorksheetFunction.Proper(WorksheetFunction.Text(DateSerial(2018, i, 1), "[$-40C]MMMM"))

    DIM_ARRAY_elmt = DIM_DATE_SUB & DIM_DATE_MOD_YEAR & ".&[" & YEAR_i_max & "]" & ".&[" & TRIMESTRE_i & "]" & ".&[" & MONTH_i & "]"
    TRUE_ARRAY(i) = DIM_ARRAY_elmt

    Debug.Print "Month    "; i; TRUE_ARRAY(i)

    Next

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields(DIM_DATE_PTF).VisibleItemsList = TRUE_ARRAY

    MONTH_i = WorksheetFunction.Proper(WorksheetFunction.Text(DateSerial(2018, i, 1), "[$-40C]MMMM"))

End Sub
Private Sub Cycle_Date(YEAR_i_max As String, TRIMESTRE_i As String, MONTH_i As String, MONTH_i_max As Integer)


        DATE_i_min = StdFilter(SheetName, "DATE_i_min")
        DATE_i_max = StdFilter(SheetName, "DATE_i_max")
        ReDim TRUE_ARRAY(1 To 2)
        Erase TRUE_ARRAY
        ReDim TRUE_ARRAY(1 To DATE_i_max)

    If DATE_i_min = DATE_i_max Then ' Fork-out scenario begin

        i = 1

        DATE_i = WorksheetFunction.Proper(WorksheetFunction.Text(DateSerial(YEAR_i_max, MONTH_i_max, i), "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS"))

        DIM_ARRAY = DIM_DATE_SUB & DIM_DATE_MOD_YEAR & ".&[" & YEAR_i_max & "]" & ".&[" & TRIMESTRE_i & "]" & ".&[" & MONTH_i & "]" & ".&[" & DATE_i & "]"

        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields(DIM_DATE_PTF).VisibleItemsList = Array(DIM_ARRAY)

        Exit Sub

    End If ' Fork-out scenario end



    For i = DATE_i_min To DATE_i_max ' Loop through

        DATE_i = Format(DateSerial(YEAR_i_max, MONTH_i_max, i), "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS")

        DIM_ARRAY_elmt = DIM_DATE_SUB & DIM_DATE_MOD_YEAR & ".&[" & YEAR_i_max & "]" & ".&[" & TRIMESTRE_i & "]" & ".&[" & MONTH_i & "]" & ".&[" & DATE_i & "]"
        TRUE_ARRAY(i) = DIM_ARRAY_elmt

    Debug.Print "Date      "; Format(i, "00 "); TRUE_ARRAY(i)

    Next

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields(DIM_DATE_PTF).VisibleItemsList = TRUE_ARRAY

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, the best debugging is to pass the Array with hardcoded values and to see whether it works. Like this:

```
..._DATE_PTF)..VisibleItemsList = Array(CDate("08.04.2018"), CDate("09.05.2018"))
```

If it works, try to find a way to pass the values in the Array as variables.